# Excel formula to change the value of another cell?

Tags: c#, excel, user-defined-functions

is it possible to force an [UDF] user-defined-function to return result on a cell we specify ?
in another words : if I execute an UDF in the cell **A1**  it will return result in **A2** cell , but what if I want to change **A2** by another cell ?

Comment: A UDF can only return a value to the cell containing the function*, so a function in A1 can't return a value to A2.  [*Without some fairly complex workarounds]

Comment: I checked My code and I find that I make the function return result in the cell below

Comment: Then you should show your code. I'd like to see how you do that...

Comment: you can take a look on my previous post : Sorry but that's all what I can provide to you

Comment: Your previous post doesn't provide any clues about this question, so I will point you back to my first comment.

Comment: in fact they are related to each other : in my previous post i was searching why when I delete the first row (where mu formula is executed) I'm getting the described exception , and because i haven't a clear answer I post the current question to try to write a formula on a sheet and get result in another sheet ...

Comment: If you have no access to the UDF code then you're stuck with how it currently functions, but there's nothing stopping you (for example) putting "=A2" in A5

Comment: it's a smart solution ;) but the result is not a simple Integer or string , it's a table ;) thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.......a UDF will only return a value to the cell in which it resides.  You could include a Calculate event macro in the worksheet.  The Calculate macro could respond to the value that the UDF returns to **A1** and change **A2** accordingly.

Another approach is to have the UDF return an array and place the UDF to span both **A1** and **A2**

**EDIT:**

Here is a very simple example of getting a UDF to fill more than one cell.

In B1, enter: 7

Install the following UDF:

```
Public Function circlee(r As Double)
    Dim ary(1 To 3, 1 To 1) As Double
    ary(1, 1) = 2 * r
    ary(2, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Pi() * 2 * r
    ary(3, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Pi() * r * r
    circlee = ary
End Function
```

Then hi-light cells A1 thru A3 and type the array formula:

=circlee(B1)

Because it is an array formula, it must be entered with **CNTRL-SHFT-ENTER** rather than just the **ENTER** key.

You should see in cells A1 thru A3 the diameter, circumference and area of a circle whose radius is in B1

Comment: what if i write/execute the formula on the **A1** cell and it generate me a result (table) starting from **A2** (my _UDF_ was coded to act like that) and I want to shift the table on top by deleting the first row where the Function  was written(all that from a c# code) --> this scenario causes me an exception (the value of the header of the first column change to :Unable to get the Find property of the Range class )

Comment: thank you very much,
this is not what I asked for; maybe I didn't describe very well what I need 
here is my request :
I have an UDF (from an addin that I haven't access to his code)
this function; when I write it in a cell it generate me result (from a data base) in the cell below (I think it was coded to act like that); so every time I get result I have to delete the first row to get only a table on my sheet , so I'm asking if I can write a function in a cell A1 sheetone and get result on cell A5sheetThree for example